# convergence of infinite sum of integer values of integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow  {\mathbb R} $ is Lebesgue integrable, prove $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N } f(x+n)$ converges for almost everywhere x. This is a question discussed with friends. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By the Monotone Convergence Theorem
$$
\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq 0}|f(x+n)|dx=\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_0^1|f(x+n)|dx=\int_0^{+\infty }|f(y)|dy<\infty.
$$
This proves that the measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow [0,+\infty]$ given by $g(x):=\sum_{n\geq 0}|f(x+n)|$ is integrable over $(0,1)$. In particular, it is finite almost everywhere on $(0,1)$. Adapt the argument to every interval $(k,k+1)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. You obtain that the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}f(x+n)$ converges absolutely almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks, then what if $\sum f(n^2x)$ instead of $\sum f(n+x)$? In this case MCT does not apply since the interval of integral is shrinking, i.e. if we try [0,1] again, $\int_0^1 |f(n^2x)|$ overlaps as we change $n$.

Comment: @Lee You should let the question as it was, and if you think my answer was correct, you could even accept it. If you want to ask another question, ask another question. If you don't go by this kind of rules, I'm not sure people will keep helping you.

Answer (score 0):

[In reply to the edited question]

Why not just change variables?
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(n^2 x) \, dx = \frac{1}{n^2} \int_{\mathbb R} f(y) \, dy
$$
so that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \sum_n f(n^2 x) \, dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \|f\|_{L^1}
$$
after using MCT.